# Homework probability help

Tags: probability

A committee of 3 students is chosen at random from a group of 4 seniors and 6 juniors.  What is the probability that the committee will have at least 1 senior?

I'm not sure where to start really.  I tried making a list showing the possible ways to have 1 senior, but i'm completely lost.

1s 2j, 2s 1j, 3s 0j: Is this even going towards the right place? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

X = event that committee has no senior, and Y = event that committee has at least 1 senior.

P(X) = C(6,3)/C(10,3) = 20/120 = 1/6. So P(Y) = 1 - P(X) = 1 - 1/6 = 5/6

Answer (score 1):

On the first pick, the probability of it NOT being a senior is $\frac{6}{10}$.  On the second pick (assuming we picked a junior on the first) the probability of it NOT being a senior is $\frac{5}{9}$.  For the third pick the probability is similarly $\frac{4}{8}$.  The probability of having chosen a committee with at least one senior is then 
$$ 1 - (\frac{6}{10} \frac{5}{9} \frac{4}{8}) $$